# Set AlternateItemTemplate Manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

Is there a way to set AlternateItemTemlate manually?
I suffered from this question more than once.

I want to use it only for the last item.
Maybe `ItemDataBound` event can be a solution but i can not figured out.

Only useful questions that I've found:

- [Is there a similar way to AlternateItemTemplate to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611767/is-there-a-similar-way-to-alternateitemtemplate-to-do-this)
- [How can i get last record value from repeater control.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371680/how-can-i-get-last-record-value-from-repeater-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemDataBound` is indeed a possible option, but for it to work, you would need the total count of the repeater items, so you can identify the last item:

```
protected void rptDummy_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    int itemsCount = ((List<SomeClass>)rptDummy.DataSource).Count;

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    { 
        if(e.Item.ItemIndex == itemsCount - 1)
        {
            //Do Things here
        }
    }
}
```

You could even have two placeholders within the same template, one specially for the last item:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder id="phIsNotLastOne" runat="server">Is not last</asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder id="phIsLastOne" runat="server">Is last</asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
protected void rptDummy_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    long itemsCount = ((List<SomeClass>)rptDummy.DataSource).Count;

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    { 
        PlaceHolder phIsLastOne = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("phIsLastOne");
        PlaceHolder phIsNotLastOne = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("phIsNotLastOne");
        phIsLastOne.Visible = e.Item.ItemIndex == itemsCount - 1;
        phIsNotLastOne.Visible = !this.phIsLastOne.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This can work fine. I was curious about handling the poblem only using repeater items. I also find a response similar to yours: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815483/asp-net-repeater-eval)

Comment: What do you mean, without any placeholder? What kind of handling do you need for the last item?

Comment: I want to use `AlternateItemTemlate` or another repeater item which runs only at the last item.

Comment: Yeah, it is possible, you could implement a custom repeater with an additional template, LastItemTemplate or something.

Comment: It seems the only solution. Thanks :)